# Multiple Tile Types Tile container in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am using Tile container[`sap.m.TileContainer`] to display some Micro charts in the app. I like the generic Tile control that has a header, footer, content structure. But Tile Controller does include `sap.m.GenericTile` as a aggregation. So as a workaround, I have wrapped generic Tiles inside Custom Tiles and it works fine.

I need to include different tile types in the same Tile Container[Custom Tile, Generic Tile inside custom Tile, slide Tile inside custom Tile]. Some tiles have 1X1 frame and some have 2X1 frames. can I create all these variants in the same Tile container.

I tried to do that but it does not seem to work. The space between tiles get disrupted if I try to display a 1X2 Tiles. It gets hidden behind the next tile.

Any example would be of great help.

Should I just dump the generic Tiles and build my custom tiles with defined width and height. In that case, I am worried about the overall responsiveness of the screen.

Any suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.